# What is the default value of n_estimators in xgboost model?

Tags: parameters, tree, classification, xgboost

I am using gridsearchCV to tune the parameters (lambda, gamma, max_depth, eta) of the xgboost classifier model. I don't set early stopping or n_estimator value. And it takes a lot of time to run gs.fit(). I want to know is there a default value of n_estimators for xgboost. Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

In version 1.5, the sklearn-API version `XGBClassifier` [defaults to 100](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/46c46829ce9e2aaf5acfed7278ac16f95a6b0bbf/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L368), whereas the native-API [defaults to 10](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.train).

Answer (score 5):

Default values for XGBClassifier:

```
n_estimators=100
```

Details are available here: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, gpu_id=-1,
              importance_type='gain', interaction_constraints='',
              learning_rate=0.300000012, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=6,
              min_child_weight=1, missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()',
              n_estimators=100, n_jobs=12, num_parallel_tree=1,
              objective='multi:softprob', random_state=0, reg_alpha=0,
              reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=None, subsample=1,
              tree_method='exact', use_label_encoder=False,
              validate_parameters=1, verbosity=None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I checked that, the default n_estimatorss is 100.